# MySQL View gives different result sets

Tags: mysql

I made dump of MySQL database. Before dumping i cleared all data. Then i restore dump into other database. Database has several tables and view collecting data from these tables. I faced with some strange behavior: 
the result set when i do "select * from view" gives me not-empty set, but 
if i execute query from body of view i got a empty set, which is correct because tables are empty. I deleted view and created it again. Results are same - empty sets.
Why did the view "remember" the data? Is there any cache?

Comment: A view in MySQL should return the same exact result set as the underlying SQL it contains.  Check your process/steps to make sure this is really reproducible.

Comment: The problem arose due to the fact that the table name consists of the database name and the table name in the query body for the view in the dump . Since the names of the old and new bases are different, the view turned to the old base.